# How to load messages faster? EWS C#

Tags: c#, load, exchangewebservices

I have a question about loading methods for EWS. I have a lot of messages in my outlook and I'm also using EWS and WinForms.

Right know my code is this:

```
while (more)
        {
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults1 = allItemsFolder.FindItems("System.Message.DateReceived:01/01/2011..12/31/2022", iv);

            foreach (var item in findResults1)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage))
                {
                    listik.Add(item);
                }
            }
            more = findResults1.MoreAvailable;
            if (more)
            {
                iv.Offset += 1000;
            }
        }
```

It took 12 minutes already for me for running my application and I decided to stop it, because something is wrong. I think I have more than 61k messages.

*The idea is to show only those messages, which have my criteria, like email address. So, I should go through all the messages and folders and put suitable in one list to show them. I'm not sure how to do this better.*

Anyone can help me with that?

Edit//Added more code

```
        PropertySet psPropSet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties)
        {
            RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text
        };
```

Added more code:

```
foreach (var item in listik)
            {
                if (item != null)
                {
                    if (((EmailMessage)(item))?.From?.Address != null)
                    {
                        var d = ((EmailMessage)(item)).From.Address;
                        if (d.Contains(comboBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()))
                        {
                            item.Load(psPropSet);

                            emails.Add((EmailMessage)item);

                            if (item.Subject != null)
                            {
                                listBox1.Items.Add(item.Subject);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

I found a link from Microsoft:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/email-properties-and-elements-in-ews-in-exchange

It's about first-class properties and I can see here EWS element - FROM, but I can't figure out how to set it in iv.PropertySet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way how it's working. Thanks, everyone for your help.

```
iv.PropertySet = new PropertySet(EmailMessageSchema.From, ItemSchema.Subject);
        while (more)
        {
            FindItemsResults<Item> findResults1 = allItemsFolder.FindItems(iv);

            foreach (var item in findResults1)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.EmailMessage))
                {
                    listik.Add(item);
                }
            }
            more = findResults1.MoreAvailable;
            if (more)
            {
                iv.Offset += 1000;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try to remove the search and try again its pretty pointless anyway with such a broad date range, the all items folder is a search folder so your applying one search on top of the other which generally doesn't work well. Also use a property set to limit the result that is returned to just the properties you want which will also make the query run faster eg

```
     iv.PropertySet =
     new PropertySet(
           BasePropertySet.IdOnly,
           ItemSchema.Subject);
```

Comment: Do you mean to remove this? **allItemsFolder.FindItems("System.Message.DateReceived:01/01/2011..12/31/2022", iv);** But then how I will get all my messages?

Comment: I added more code to clarify my situation. Is it possible to get **From.Address** in PropertySet?

Answer (score 1):

No email app, including Outlook, ever loads **all** messages in a folder. Use a virtual listview/grid and retrieve the messages (using the appropriate offset) only when displaying them to an end user.

Comment: The idea is to show only those messages, which have my criteria, like email address. So, I should go through all the messages and folders and put suitable in one list to show them. I'm not sure how to do this better.

Comment: I added more code to clarify my situation.

Comment: I understand that, but if the messages are not visible to the end-user (they are outside of the list view bound), do not load them from Exchange. When and if the user scrolls to make them visible, load them only then. No user will ever scroll through 60,000 items.